# Rails 4 relationship issues, On login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, has-many, belongs-to

I'm not sure what has changed getting this error when trying to login:

```
ERROR:  relation "tags" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" O...
```

The tag model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :unread_count, :user_feeds

  has_many :taggings
  has_many :feeds, through: :taggings
end
```

The tagging model:

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :feed
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And the user relationships:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :coupon
  has_many :subscriptions, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :feeds, through: :subscriptions
  has_many :entries, through: :feeds
  has_many :imports, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :billing_events, as: :billable, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :taggings, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
  has_many :sharing_services, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :unread_entries, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :starred_entries, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :saved_searches, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :actions, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :plan
end
```

This error is new and came right after I tried to install the intercom.io gem. I removed the gem, did a gem cleanup, reset the db and still the same error.

Not sure what happened, if anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate it.

Comment: Try running your migrations via `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: Wow, for some reason the tags table wasn't present. Migrations are all messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked missing tables, and that was the problem.