# Rails 4 Relationship Issue extended

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Similar to this problem posted here but im not sure if the solution is applicable.
[Rails 4 relationship issues, On login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20445353/rails-4-relationship-issues-on-login)

I keep getting this message while running the set up in localhost:3000.

ERROR:  relation "XXX" does not exist

LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT "XXX".* FROM "XXX" INNER JOIN ....

I wish to (hopefully) understand how this error came about and need someone's kind help to advise how to troubleshoot it.

Please feel free to let me know which part of the code do I need to paste here for your understanding.

Comment: normally this means that DB you are connecting to doesn't have the tables in it (Migrations haven't been run, etc..)

Comment: make sure you run `rake db:migrate` before using your new DB structure with your ruby code.

Comment: Ok sorry, Im quite new to this. Need some additional explanation from you folks. Appreciate it!  

Im running this on localhost and have edited the code. The new table is not yet on the repository and hence no new data has been input yet. 

Would running rake db:migrate work? Or does it mean I have to make the changes to the development version on the repository first before running migration?

Oh lastly, will rake db:migrate screw up anything or delete any data?