# How to push changes from Bitbucket to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sublimetext2, bitbucket

I'm new to programming, learnt languages but this part I have no clue.

I'm working on a app that is on bitbucket and on Heroku cloud.

I am not exactly very clear how the bibucket repository interacts with Heroku and also my local offline commandprompt+sublimetext+PG database.

So what I'm doing is i have made some changes physically on Bitbucket (manually on their website) based on the changes Ive made and viewed (offline on localhost 3000) and wanted to push it to Heroku to have the changes online. There does not seem to be any buttons on bitbucket for that purposes and I guess I have to do it through the command prompt.

In that case how do I make those changes (command lines) and update the sublime+PG on the local server? I seen a few codes on git and suspect those are it (like git push -v) which lists the repositories but I don't wish to test and end up screwing the codes. Please advise if there are easier to do any of the above.

**Note that I want the changes to be on Heroku because of this error.
[Rails 4 Relationship Issue extended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139291/rails-4-relationship-issue-extended)**

Also what the difference between pulling and pushing changes? I'm reading the git definitions but it isn't saying much. Just that pull is pulling data from other repository to I'm not sure where. Push is to update remote refs with associated objects.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're new, let me explain what you need:

> Heroku uses an amazing deployment process which based on the [`git` scm
>   system](http://git-scm.com/). This means that you just need to "push" your git
>   respository to Heroku in order for it to deploy your latest revision
>   of code
>
> The problem you cited is you're trying to push from `bitbucket`
>   directly. `Bitbucket` / `github` are essentially just cloud
>   repositories where you can store your code, and is not where Heroku
>   can "read" your files from

To get this working, as you've stated in your comments, you need to push from your computer. This is achieved by [creating a remote repository for Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git), and then pushing to that, like this:

```
$ git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:yourherokuapp.git
$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "Latest Commit"
$ git push heroku master
```

Comment: Thanks Rich. I followed those steps and now have the following when i type git remote -v

`all ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myname/projectname.git (fetch)`
`all ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myname/projectname.git (push)`
`all git@heroku.com:projectname.git (push)`
`heroku git@heroku.com:projectname.git (fetch)`
`heroku git@heroku.com:projectname.git (push)`
`origin https://user@bitbucket.org/user/bitbucketprojectname.git (fetch)`
`origin https://user@bitbucket.org/user/bitbucketprojectname.git (push)`

Is this correct?

Comment: Did you not add the heroku repo to your git remote repos?

Comment: Thing is im not sure, I believe I have just added it which resulted in the codes above when i typed `git remote -v`

And now I have some error on overwriting files and commit/stashing before merging

Comment: Why don't you try setting `git remote rm heroku` and then you can do `git remote add heroku git@heroku.com`. This should add the repo for you

Comment: I explained in the answer lol. It removed any remote `herokue` repo on your system & adds it again. You need to have a Heroku repo to push your git to Heroku, allowing you to deploy the latest code

Comment: I see, i removed and added back a generic one. 
Which means I had the 2 heroku repo above! Thanks for clarifying!